# Amazon S3 Images Expiring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Images on Amazon S3 are expiring, and therefore not displaying on the page when a user makes a post.

I'm using Backbone + Rails, so I load each user's picture url on page load. This is stored in a Backbone model, which lives in the user's browser. When a user makes a new post, I want to display his/her image next to the post. When the page first loads, this works fine, but after the image expires, if the user makes a post, the image doesn't display, and I get an error in the console that the URL where the image is located on S3 is forbidden.

I'm in the S3 management console, but don't see where I can change the expiration time to a lot longer, or get rid of the expiration time altogether. Anyone know how to do this, or know another solution to this problem?

Comment: Simply don't define a expiration time. It's not the file expiring, it's the public URL of the file you can set to expire after a specific time

Comment: When you make a file public, it doesn't have any expiration by default. Which method do you use to set them to be public?

Comment: In the AWS S3 Management Console, I right click on the folder that has the pictures I want to make public (aka with no expiration date), and click 'Make Public'. However, when I fetch the image in Rails, it still returns the URL of the image with an 'expires' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

How you are uploading images to S3? You should make images public when uploading images.

Comment: I'm using the Carrierwave in Rails. I make the images public on S3 by right click the folder and clicking 'Make Public'.

Comment: Making the folder public is not enough, because newer file wont be public by default. You must specify public for each file when you upload it. you can achive this in Carrierwave by adding folowing line to its config

config.fog_public     = **true**